# Strange result with package listings when a string literal presents

Tags: listings

I'm using package listings to add code in a document.

Almost everything works pretty well, until I write a string literal like this:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
{
\begin{lstlisting}[language=python]
"? {a}"
\end{lstlisting}
}
\end{document}
```

this generates a very strange string, in which the blank between "?" and "{" become the following symbol:
[image]

Is this a bug of package listings? I'm seeking for a solution to this.

Comment: the strange symbol differs according to the current font. I'm using `Consolas`. In other cases it may become a small square without a question mark in it, which occurs in the example above.

I'm using xelatex.

Log file:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999992 (TeX Live 2020/W32TeX) (preloaded format=xelatex 2020.11.18)  20 FEB 2021 21:58
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 file:line:error style messages enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**test
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2020-03-06> (c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count163
\c@section=\count164
\c@subsection=\count165
\c@subsubsection=\count166
\c@paragraph=\count167
\c@subparagraph=\count168
\c@figure=\count169
\c@table=\count170
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen134
) (c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/listings.sty (c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks15
)
\lst@mode=\count171
\lst@gtempboxa=\box45
\lst@token=\toks16
\lst@length=\count172
\lst@currlwidth=\dimen135
\lst@column=\count173
\lst@pos=\count174
\lst@lostspace=\dimen136
\lst@width=\dimen137
\lst@newlines=\count175
\lst@lineno=\count176
\lst@maxwidth=\dimen138
 (c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/lstmisc.sty
File: lstmisc.sty 2020/03/24 1.8d (Carsten Heinz)
\c@lstnumber=\count177
\lst@skipnumbers=\count178
\lst@framebox=\box46
) (c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/listings.cfg
File: listings.cfg 2020/03/24 1.8d listings configuration
))
Package: listings 2020/03/24 1.8d (Carsten Heinz)
 (c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-xdvipdfmx.def
File: l3backend-xdvipdfmx.def 2020-03-12 L3 backend support: xdvipdfmx
\g__graphics_track_int=\count179
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box47
\g__pdf_backend_object_int=\count180
\g__pdf_backend_annotation_int=\count181
) (./test.aux)
\openout1 = `test.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for TS1+cmr on input line 4.
 (c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd
File: ts1cmr.fd 2019/12/16 v2.5j Standard LaTeX font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TU/lmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
\c@lstlisting=\count182
 (c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/lstlang1.sty
File: lstlang1.sty 2020/03/24 1.8d listings language file
) [1

] (./test.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 1778 strings out of 479418
 27341 string characters out of 5888104
 454354 words of memory out of 5000000
 19355 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 532346 words of font info for 25 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1348 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 28i,4n,42p,147b,1087s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s

Output written on test.pdf (1 page).
```

After I added `\XeTeXtracingfonts=1` and `\textvisiblespace`

```
\XeTeXtracingfonts=1
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\textvisiblespace
\begin{lstlisting}[language=python]
    "? {"
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

the result:
[image]

log file:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999992 (TeX Live 2020/W32TeX) (preloaded format=xelatex 2020.11.18)  21 FEB 2021 23:30
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 file:line:error style messages enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**test
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2020-03-06> (c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX file (size option)
Requested font "[lmroman10-regular]:mapping=tex-text;" at 10.0pt
 -> c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman10-regular.otf
)
\c@part=\count163
\c@section=\count164
\c@subsection=\count165
\c@subsubsection=\count166
\c@paragraph=\count167
\c@subparagraph=\count168
\c@figure=\count169
\c@table=\count170
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen134
) (c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/listings.sty (c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks15
)
\lst@mode=\count171
\lst@gtempboxa=\box45
\lst@token=\toks16
\lst@length=\count172
\lst@currlwidth=\dimen135
\lst@column=\count173
\lst@pos=\count174
\lst@lostspace=\dimen136
\lst@width=\dimen137
\lst@newlines=\count175
\lst@lineno=\count176
\lst@maxwidth=\dimen138
 (c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/lstmisc.sty
File: lstmisc.sty 2020/03/24 1.8d (Carsten Heinz)
\c@lstnumber=\count177
\lst@skipnumbers=\count178
\lst@framebox=\box46
) (c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/listings.cfg
File: listings.cfg 2020/03/24 1.8d listings configuration
))
Package: listings 2020/03/24 1.8d (Carsten Heinz)
 (c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-xdvipdfmx.def
File: l3backend-xdvipdfmx.def 2020-03-12 L3 backend support: xdvipdfmx
\g__graphics_track_int=\count179
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box47
\g__pdf_backend_object_int=\count180
\g__pdf_backend_annotation_int=\count181
) (./test.aux)
\openout1 = `test.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for TS1+cmr on input line 5.
 (c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd
File: ts1cmr.fd 2019/12/16 v2.5j Standard LaTeX font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TU/lmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
\c@lstlisting=\count182
 (c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/lstlang1.sty
File: lstlang1.sty 2020/03/24 1.8d listings language file
) [1

] (./test.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 1778 strings out of 479418
 27341 string characters out of 5888104
 454355 words of memory out of 5000000
 19355 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 532346 words of font info for 25 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1348 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 28i,4n,42p,147b,1087s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s

Output written on test.pdf (1 page).
```

Comment: You are not using consolas in your example. Are you sure exactly this example produce the problem? Is your tex system up-to-date?

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. Please, check the example.

Comment: @egreg I copied the code directly. That produces the problem, maybe there're extra messages needed, but i cannot provide it for this time because i don't know what exactly it is.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer I' m not using Consolas here in my example, so it simply produces a small square, as i mentioned in the "comment".

Comment: Show the log-file of your example.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer log file provided :)

Comment: this doesn't load ctex, so it is not the log of your example. If it shows your problem, check if the space is really a normal space.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Sorry, that log is generated after i delete ctex package using. It still generates the problem. But of course it's my fault not making it clear.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer i'm sure it's a normal space. Well, this question may really need extra details, but i just dont know how to provide them. It just repeatedly produce the problem in the most simple example... I feel really puzzled, to be frank.

Comment: the language python forces a visible space there, and is looks as if your font doesn't have it.  What happens if you type `\textvisiblespace` outside the listing?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer wow, it generates another strange symbol. Does that illustrate the specific space `listing` using is missing in my character set? How should I fix that?

Comment: Add `\XeTeXtracingfonts=1` before \documentclass to a small document using \textvisiblespace and then show the log-file.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you, I added them.

Comment: but your output looks fine. That is how \textvisiblespace looks like.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer So, how should I turn those `\textvisiblespace`s in the `lstlisting` to normal spaces?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer And it seems `Consolas` doesn't have a correct `\textvisiblespace`, But I dont really care that, I just want it to be a normal space :)

Comment: `showstringspaces=false`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you so much! That really helps!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The python language makes by default spaces visible, that is the symbol you are seeing.

You can deactivate this with  `showstringspaces=false`.